# Ruby on Rails: Postgres Relation 'lists' does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rails-postgresql

I'm getting a weird error. I had sqlite3 working and now switching over to postgres, i'm getting this error.

I have migrations, and I had to add a new column.

**create_ideas** migration

```
class CreateIdeas < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ideas do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :picture

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :ideas, :lists
  end
end
```

**add_list_id_column_to_ideas** migration

```
class AddListIdColumnToIdeas < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :ideas, :list_id, :integer

  end
end
```

What is wrong with my foreign key? I get the error when I do `rake db:migrate`

I have another migration with foreign key, and no errors yet? Maybe its catching the first error first before seeing the other one, but I have this one too:

**create_comments** migration

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :user_name
      t.text :body
      t.integer :idea_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :comments, :ideas
  end
end
```

last migration I have **create_lists**

```
class CreateLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lists do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :picture

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any clue why I'm getting errors?

Thanks

edit

my relationships

comments model

```
belongs_to :idea
```

idea model

```
belongs_to :list
has_many :comments
```

list model

```
has_many :ideas
```

Comment: The `CreateLists` migration has already been run before the `CreateIdeas` correct?

Comment: I think `CreateIdeas` is first to run. Also, to give a sense of my relations: in my comments model I have `belongs_to :ideas` and then in my idea model I have `belongs_to :list` and `has_many :comments` and then in my list model I have `has_many :ideas`

Comment: Just a guess but shouldn't `CreateLists` be run first to create the list table before trying to make the list table a foreign key?

Comment: @Deekor hmmm I'm not sure? I'm new to ruby on rails. How would I create this? The migration file name is ordered where create_ideas is first?

Comment: @Deekor I did a little digging, and I did `rake db:migrate:up VERSION = 2013...` the version number of create_list file and then I tried `rake db:migrate` but it still gives errors. I also tried to do the version of just the create_idea also, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm it should just migrate in the order that you created the migrations.